# Show only even numbers from a data set

Tags: r

I am trying to extract only the even numbers from the "cars" data set.

I know I need to create a new function.

I have come this far:

```
Is.even = function(x) x %% 2 == 0
```

When I enter in:

```
Is.even(cars[1])
```

It gives me back a logical response. I want to only display the actual even numbers in integer form and hide the odd numbers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. The function is comparing each element of the vector and returning the result of the comparison - true or false. To get the value of the elements, you need to subset the vector based on which comparisons are true. So `cars[1][Is.even(cars[1])]` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from @neilfws' suggestion, if you pass your values as a vector you can also use `Filter`

```
Filter(Is.even, cars[, 1])
#[1]  4  4  8 10 10 10 12 12 12 12 14 14 14 14 16 16 18 18 18 18 20 20 20 20 20 22 24 24 24 24
```